# Value iteration in HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

### Description

I want to make this view work,
[image]

I'm using a loop for this table, I managed to do a loop for the input part of the id.
[image]

The input id has followed the increment according to the number of iterations

### Problem

However, I also want variables like input id to apply in the value input.

Ex,

Iteration 1 > `<input id="id-sensor-1" type="text" value="{{ variable-loopindex1 }}">`

Iteration 2 > `<input id="id-sensor-2" type="text" value="{{ variable-loopindex2 }}">`

Iteration 3 > `<input id="id-sensor-3" type="text" value="{{ variable-loopindex3 }}">`

I'm using Python Flask and HTML Template. **How do I get the conditions I want to work?** **Or is there any other solution?** I'm at a loss to search for the keywords. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Store variables in an iterable object, such as variables：

```
{% for variable in variables %}
    <input id="id-sensor-{{loop.index0}}" type="text" value="{{ variable }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want the value variable to match the loop index as well. like this `value={{ variable-loop.index0 }}`